# A non-trivial combinatorial optimization

Tags: graph-theory, approximation-algorithms, tree, combinatorics

So I stumble over this problem in which I couldn't find anything similar in the literature. I am not even sure if it is NP-hard or solvable in polynomial time. Any thought or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Suppose I give you a $d$ dimensional vector $x$, with rational entries in the range $[0,1]$. Similarly, I also give you $d$ dimensional $n^2$ vectors $y_{i,j}$ for $i,j \in \{1,...,n\}$ with entries in the range $[0,1]$.

I want to find a directed spanning tree with each vertex has exactly one parent (except the root) $T$ of $n$ vertices such that:

$\| x - \circ_{(i,j) \in edges(T) }y_{i,j}\|_1$  is minimized, where $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard product (entry-wise product) between the vectors. I'm also fine with $l_2$ norm. I.e,

$\| x - \circ_{(i,j) \in edges(T) }y_{i,j}\|_2$  is minimized.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, then surely it is NP-hard, even with d=1.   First, note that the problem "given an edge-weighted graph and a target $T$, is there a spanning tree of total weight exactly $T$" is NP-complete.  (By reduction from subset-sum: given $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ and a target $T$, construct multigraph $G=(V,E)$ with $V=\{0,\ldots,n\}$, where $E$ has two copies of each edge $(i,i+1)$ ($0 \le i < n$), one with weight $x_i$, the other with weight 0.)  Next, note that for $d=1$ your problem (with the Hadamard product replaced by a sum) generalizes that problem.

Comment: Your solution sounds just right. I suppose when you say my problem generalizes that problem, it means replacing x by log(x) and the product of y's by sum of log(y)'s?

I really appreciate your simple explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NP-hard even for $d=1$ by reduction from the (strongly NP-hard) Product Partition problem.

**Lemma 1.** *The problem (with either objective function) is NP-hard, even for $d=1$.*

*Proof sketch.* Given an instance $W=(W_1, \ldots, W_n)\in \mathbb N^n$ of Product Partition, the reduction outputs the instance $(G, x)$ of OP's problem where $x=\sqrt {\prod_{i=1}^n W_i}$,
and the multi-digraph $G$ is a path with $2n$ edges,
specifically the vertex set is $V=[n+1]$,
and, for each $i\in[n]$,
there are two edges $(i, i+1)_1$ and $(i, i+1)_2$ from $i$ to $i+1$,
the first with weight $W_i$, the second with weight 1.

(If a digraph without multi-edges is desired,
just replace each second edge $(i, i+1)_2$
by two edges  $(i, v_i)$ and $(v_i, i+1)$,
each with weight 1, where $v_i$ is a new, artificial vertex.)

This completes the reduction.

Each rooted spanning tree $t$ rooted at vertex 1 in $G$
corresponds bijectively to the subset $S(t)\subseteq [n]$
such that $S(t) = \{i\in [n] : (i, i+1)_1 \in t\}$,
and vice versa. (Note that if $(i, i+1)_1$ is not present in $t$
then $(i, i+1)_2$ must be, or, if the modification that removes
multi-edges is used, then each edge $(i, v_i)$ is
always present, and $(v_i, i+1)$ is present iff $(i, i+1)_1$ is not.)

The product of the "vectors" on the edges in a given $t$
is then $\prod_{i\in S(t)} W_i$.
So the optimal cost for this instance of OP's problem is zero
iff there is a subset with product $x$.

(Technically,
OP's problem definition doesn't explicitly specify a graph,
just edge weights, so presumably the graph is supposed to be
complete, in which case give every edge not mentioned above
weight, say, $x+1$.  Then the same argument works,
as any tree using such an edge has weight at least $x+1$.)
$~~~\Box$

Note that this reduction "almost" shows *strong* NP-hardness.
It doesn't quite, because $x$, which must be given as part of the input
for the decision variant, is exponential in $n$.
However, $x$ can be implicitly encoded by giving $W$ (even in unary)
and with this encoding this (special case of) OP's problem is strongly NP-hard.

Comment: Note that essentially the same reduction would show that minimizing either objective function, even with $x=0$, is NP-hard.  This is essentially the same as the solution here to a related question: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53908/shortest-path-with-affine-updates-and-fixed-dimension/53920#53920 .