# Shortest path with affine updates and fixed dimension

Tags: ds.algorithms, np-hardness, shortest-path

One may look at the shortest path problem on a weighted directed graph with weights on $\mathbb{Q}$ as the problem of minimizing a rational value $x$ which is updated at each edge of the graph with the label $v$ of the edge. So essentially, we can rewrite the labels of a weighted graph and write updates $x := x + v$. The shortest path problem then becomes the problem of minimising the value of $x$. This is known to be solvable in polynomial time.

Now suppose we generalise this to a constant number of variables $x$. Now we consider at each step an update of a vector $\vec{x} = A \vec{x} + \vec{b}$ where $A \in \mathbb{Q}^{n \times n}, \vec{b} \in \mathbb{Q}^{n \times 1}$. The matrix $A$ and the vector $b$ may be different at each edge. At the target node one computes an affine function $o = \vec{c} \vec{x} + d$ where $\vec{c} \in \mathbb{Q}^{n \times 1}$ and $d \in \mathbb{Q}$. This target function may be different for each final node. The optimisation problem is to determine the minimal value of $o$.

Is it known whether this problem for fixed $n$ is solvable in polynomial time?

Comment: Is the path required to be simple?  If so the problem is NP-hard even for $n=1$ by reduction from Longest Path (i.e. min-weight simple path where each edge has weight -1).  Or to simplify do you want to assume the graph is a DAG?

Comment: @NeilYoung, the path is not required to be simple and there is no assumption that the graph is a DAG.

Comment: @NeilYoung isn't it that if the case of the graph being a DAG is NP-hard then that implies the general case is NP-hard?

Comment: Yes.  Also, note that if the graph is not a DAG it may contain infinitely long paths, which one has to take some care about in the problem definition...

Comment: @NealYoung, I think replacing max/min with sup/inf in the optimization takes care of that concern.  (This is the standard way of formulating an optimization problem when optimizing over infinitely many possibilities.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lemma 1.** *The problem is <s>strongly</s> NP-hard for $n=2$, even in directed acyclic graphs (DAGs).*

*[EDIT: strong NP-hardness depends on the encoding.  See the comments at the end.]*

*Proof sketch.* The proof is by reduction from the [Product Partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Variants_and_generalizations), which is strongly NP-hard [1]:

Product Partition
$~~~$  **input:** *integers $W=(w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n)$*
$~$  **output:** *is there a **balanced** subset $S\subseteq [n]$, that is, one such that $\prod_{i\in S} w_i = \prod_{i\not\in S} w_i$?*

Fix a Product-Partition instance $W$.

**Observation 1.** *A given subset $S$ is balanced iff $\vec 1 \cdot \vec v(S) \le T$,
where* $\vec v(S) = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
\prod_{i\in S} w_i\\
\prod_{i\not\in S} w_i
\end{array}\right]$
and $T= 2\sqrt {\prod_{i=1}^n w_i}$.

(The observation follows from the fact that, for $c$ fixed and $z\ge 0$, the function $z\mapsto z + c/z$ is uniquely minimized at $z=\sqrt c$, where it takes the value $2\sqrt c$.)

Given $W=(w_1, \ldots, w_n)$, the reduction constructs an instance $G=(V,E)$ of OP's problem as follows.

We describe $G$ as a multigraph (with multi-edges).  It can be converted into a regular graph by the standard technique of splitting each edge into a path of length 2 by adding a new intermediate vertex.

We take $G$ to have vertex set $V=[n+1]$. For each vertex $i\in [n]$, there are two directed edges $(i, i+1)_1$ and $(i, i+1)_2$ from $i$ to $i+1$,
labeled, respectively, with the following two matrices:
$$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
w_i & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right],
~~\text{and}~~
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & w_i
\end{array}\right].
$$
We label the vertices $1$ and $n+1$ with the vector $\vec 1 \in \mathbb Z^2$,
so that the starting value of $x$ (in OP's problem definition)
is $\vec 1$.
(OP's problem allows each edge to have a vector associated with it.
For each edge the associated vector is $\vec 0$.)
This completes the reduction.

To see that it is correct,
note that the $2^n$ paths from 1 to $n+1$ in this graph
correspond bijectively to the $2^n$ subsets $S\subseteq [n]$.
A given $1\to n$ path $P$ (considered as a set of edges)
corresponds to the set
$S(P)=\{i\in [n] : (i, i+1)_1\}\in P\}$.
Further, the objective value achieved by $P$ is
$$
\big(\textstyle\prod_{i\in S(P)} w_i\big)
+\big(\textstyle\prod_{i\not\in S(P)} w_i\big)
= \vec v(S(P))\cdot \vec 1.
$$
Per Observation 1, this value is at most $T = 2\sqrt{\prod_{i} w_i}$
iff $S(P)$ is balanced. $~~~\Box$

[EDIT: The reduction above doesn't show *strong* NP-hardness
with the obvious encoding of OP's problem as a decision problem,
which requires encoding the target $T$,
whose value (in the standard encoding) is exponentially large.
However, the input can encode $T$ implicitly
by giving the $n$ $w_i$'s (whose values are polynomially large).
With this encoding, the problem is strongly NP-hard.
See [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16902/subset-sum-vs-subset-product-strong-vs-weak-np-hardness#comment120024_16902)
for related discussion.]

---

[1] *Ng, C. T.; Barketau, M. S.; Cheng, T. C. E.; Kovalyov, Mikhail Y.*, [**“Product partition” and related problems of scheduling and systems reliability: computational complexity and approximation**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2010.05.034), Eur. J. Oper. Res. 207, No. 2, 601-604 (2010). [ZBL1205.68174](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1205.68174).

Comment: Closely related: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/53932/8237 .